# Embed webform in block and on submit load file from currently displayed node

Tags: webforms

I need to create a "Download this whitepaper" functionality similar to [this one](http://learn.getpantheon.com/amazing-drupal-launches-1.html?agn=All%20Site%20Visitors&cn=Display%20-%20Remarketing%20-%20Image%20Ads&chan=Google%20Display&kw=&off=8%20Amazing%20Drupal%20Launches&dev=DesktopTablet&gclid=CO3NxpXL88ACFSdk7Aod90MAxw).

So far this is what I've done:

- Created 'whitepaper' content type with file field
- Created 'whitepaper' webform (as a block). Contains fields for firstname, last name and email.
- Displaying the 'whitepaper' webform block on 'whitepaper' node types.

Here is where I need some guidance.

When I am viewing a node of type 'whitepaper' and want to download the attached file, I fill in the form fields on the block 'whitepaper' web form. When I hit submit, I want to be able to download the file attached to the content type.

How can I achieve this?

Will I be better off writing a custom module instead of a webform form?

Comment: Personally I would just write a module for that. I'm afraid hacking around Webform's defaults would use similar amount of code. But that's just my guess and feeling, not something I *know*, so I will not post this as an answer.